# How does the visual studio debugger detect function calls?

Tags: c++, windows, function, debugging

When ive attached the visual studio debugger to a process, then add a new function breakpoint, and choose e.g. "system" as the function name. Visual studio will then detect whenever the `system()` function is called from the target process.

Is there any efficient way to detect function calls from a process using c++?

Comment: Short answer is that by using the debugging APIs provided by Windows, one can set a breakpoint and get an event (via a structured exception) when it's hit. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/debugapi/nf-debugapi-debugbreak for more information.

Comment: The debugger doesn't detect function calls. When you place a breakpoint on `system`, the debugger uses the symbols to resolve that address, and then modifies the code there to change the first instruction to cause a break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A debugger detects that a breakpoint has been hit in several ways.

The basic strategy is the software breakpoint. This means that the debugger replaces an instruction at the breakpoint target with a breakpoint trap instruction.

When the execution hits the breakpoint instruction, a CPU exception is caused which is then handled via the debugger. The debugger sees that execution has stopped at a certain address, and for a certain reason, and that confirms to it that the breakpoint has been hit.

Lastly, implementing breakpoint debugging is possible even without the help from a breakpoint instruction. A software breakpoint could be inserted into the target code as ordinary branch instruction that jumps into a routine inside debugger, rather than raising CPU exception which is handled through the debugger.

In addition to this, processors can (and do) support hardware breakpoints. Usually a very limited number of hardware breakpoints can be configured in the processor which tell it to stop at a certain address. This is less intrusive than a software breakpoint, and will work even if the code is in read-only memory.

Of course if you have a software breakpoint, the missing instruction which has been replaced has to be executed when the execution is restarted. The debugger must put the original instruction in place before resuming. But if that is all that is done, the breakpoint will effectively disappear. The breakpoint must be re-armed so that execution will stop if it is hit again. To achieve that, the debugger can put the processor into single step mode. It can replace the original instruction, then step the code in single step mode, then put in the software breakpoint again and resume.

If the processor doesn't have a single step mode, but only a break instruction, then the processor can simulate single stepping using a temporary software breakpoint (one that doesn't have to be re-armed once executed).